# Prevent to install WIX Setup on XP

Tags: asp.net, wix, windows-installer

I have a WIX setup MSI. I want to prevent it to install on WIN XP.
I was using the InstallPrivileges property of WIX but it did not solve my problem:-

```
 <Package InstallerVersion="200"  Platform="$(var.Platform)" InstallPrivileges="limited" />
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Priyanka, You are going in wrong direction.
**InstallPrivileges** attribute is use to specify the privileges required to install the package on Windows Vista and above.
Windows vista onward by default runs most applications with least privilege access (non-admin) in an attempt to keep both malicious virus code and inexperienced end users from damaging the system.
 **limited** and **elevated** value from **InstallPrivileges** attribute specifies whether to use elevated privileges or not.
If you select **Limited** installer will run without Admin privileges and if you use  **elevated** then your installer will ask for administrator privileges using UAC prompt.This attribute will be neglected if you are running it on windows xp (**NOT SURE**).
And Now to completely block your installer to run on windows XP then you need to use [VersionNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa372495.aspx) property which will detect the version of the user's operating system.

The following sample demonstrates how to use this property to block installation of an application on operating systems prior to Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008

```
<Condition Message="This application is only supported on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, or higher.">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR (VersionNT >= 600)]]>
</Condition>
```

Refer [VersionNT values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa370556.aspx) to choose for Which OS you want to block your installer.
refer for more info [How To: Block Installation Based on OS Version](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/block_install_on_os.html)

Comment: You could possible put a condition on the interrupted dialog so that it doesn't display but to be honest the behavior you are getting is the standard and expected behavior.

Comment: Same issue as your other post - I've never seen a launch condition denial of launch show up on a welcome page. Are you running the MSI file or using a bootstrapper or something?

Comment: I dont know whether this is supported directly by WiX or not. However, you can try this approach: like create your custom action which will detect OS info and bitness of OS. just schedule your custom action before any dialogs are called by the InstallUISequence.And take necessary action on dialog/ prompt you want to display.